# Growing docker's volume on an LVM

Tags: centos, lvm, docker

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.projectatomic.io/docs/docker-storage-recommendation/) to set up docker on CentOS using the LVM. I fed it a 16G disk. It consumed 6.37GB. Now, one of my containers ran out of disk space. What do I have to do for docker to consume more space from the LVM pool and allow the container to grow?